# API for accessing API/Service Details for number of requests, errors, latency, and more?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

When visiting console.cloud.google.com, I can access the following information for a particular API:

- Requests
- Errors
- Latency
- and more

by:

1. Select the project running the API I want to know more about
2. Clicking on "APIs & Services" in the "Navigation Menu"
3. Clicking on "Enabled APIs & services"

On the "Enabled APIs & services" page, it shows which APIs I am using and the values I listed above. I can also select a particular API on that page to see a more detailed view with graphs and other information.

I would like to

1. Extract the above information, such as requests, latency, and errors
2. Extract the Methods for an API and their Requests, Errors, Latency

I would like to obtain this information over an API using `python`. How can I do this?

Also, is it possible to:

- Embed the graphs show on the "API/Service Details" page for a particular API using IFrames or something similar in another website?

Comment: 2 things: 1 - Your question [lacks focus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance/417486#417486), you should edit it. 2 - Is what you are looking for similar to [this](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python)?

Comment: You haven't got any code here for us to go off so we don't know where you're at with it. I would start by looking into the python client libraries for the Google Cloud API and see if it supports the information you want https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client

Answer (score 0):

The commenters are correct and you should (!) provide at least a preliminary attempt at a solution in code.

However, I think your question is asked in good faith and it isn't obvious how the metrics are generated for the APIs metrics pages.

The answer is that the pages use [Google Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring) service|API to do this.

You can verify this for yourself and for most every page on [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) by opening your preferred browser's developer tools and monitoring the Fetch|REST calls using the network tab.

If you use Chrome's Developer Tools (and probably if you use any other browser too), you'll get quite some detail from this page including the [Monitoring filters](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters) that the Console page is using to generate the data.

So that explains how Cloud Console does it.

How can you generate the equivalent in Python?

Google's documentation is good.

Here's an overview for using Google's [Monitoring client libraries (for Python)](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) and should give you a good start.

You can use the Developer Tools to copy-and-paste the filters that the page is using into your code to generate equivalent requests.

You can also use Google's (excellent) [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) for [Cloud Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/) to see -- for example -- how to use [`projects.timeSeries.query`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/query) which is one of the methods that the Cloud Console page uses.

The APIs Explorer documentation not only explains the request and response types but you can invoke the method (Try this method) for yourself in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

To further add on @DazWilkin's answer. You can use this code in Python to get the details from **APIs & Services > Enabled APIs & services**.

The code below uses filter `serviceruntime.googleapis.com/api/request_count` which shows the number of request you see here:

[image]

Code is also filtered by method (`resource.labels.method = "compute.v1.ZonesService.List"`) just so few entries will be returned. It is up to you if you would like to filter using methods. See [serviceruntime metric documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-serviceruntime) for more metrics (errors, latency, etc.) and [filtering guide](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters) for more details.

```
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
import time

client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
project_name = f"projects/tiph-ricconoel-batch8"

now = time.time()
seconds = int(now)
nanos = int((now - seconds) * 10 ** 9)
interval = monitoring_v3.TimeInterval(
    {
        "end_time": {"seconds": seconds, "nanos": nanos},
        "start_time": {"seconds": (seconds - 1200), "nanos": nanos},
    }
)


results = client.list_time_series(
    request={
        "name": project_name,
        "filter": 'metric.type = "serviceruntime.googleapis.com/api/request_count" AND resource.labels.method = "compute.v1.ZonesService.List"',
        "interval": interval,
        "view": monitoring_v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest.TimeSeriesView.FULL,
    }
)

print(results)
```